# android - filling ListView with array

Tags: android

I can't fill a ListView layout with an array of strings.  Here is the Activity:

```
 ListView symptomList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_Symptom);
 String symptomsArray[] = new String[1024];
 // Then I fill up symptomsArray
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_item, symptomsArray);
    symptomList.setAdapter(adapt);
```

Here is menu_item:

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:textSize="@dimen/menu_item_size"
android:text="test string"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shadowRadius="5"
android:gravity="center"
android:shadowDy="3"
android:shadowDx="3" />
```

And here is symptom.xml -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ListView_Symptom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/textured"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?  Does my public class need to extend "ListActivity".  I tried that and that didn't work.

Comment: Why do you have two exact same listview node in your XML?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing? An exception? A blank list? A populated list with blank listitems?

Comment: I just see a black screen, no list at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Eclipse is so slow running on my 5 GB Dram MacPro that it eventually worked and displayed the array in the ListView, it just took a few minutes!  Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try stripping out some of the presentational bits from your `TextView`. For example, I don't think that you want `android:layout_gravity="center"` there. Also, try setting your `ListView`'s `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`.

Comment: I tried removing the items you suggested, and I still see a black screen.  This black screen is shown after clicking a button on the splash screen to select this activity which should fill a ListView with an array of strings.